# Would it be dangerous to uninstall Python

Tags: python

I plan on uninstalling and reinstalling Python to fix pip. I, however, have a lot of python files which I worked hard on and I really don't want to lose them. Would my Python files be okay if I uninstalled Python?

Comment: Do you know that uninstalling Python will fix pip? or is it more of a case of turning it off and on again.

Comment: Hoooooooold on a second-- what OS are you on?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Python files"? Where are they saved? How did you create and edit htem?

Comment: @shadowtalker just basic scripts I wrote with IDE

Comment: @Stevo its pretty much like turning it off and on again

Comment: What python? Python 2 or Python 3? Can you also mention your OS?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Linux and a distribution like Ubuntu, you will definitely break the OS. Don't do it.

Moreover, there is no evidence that your installation is broken because of Python, and you may probably not solve your problem.

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted; this is a perfectly reasonable concern in my opinion.  Also holds true for MacOS.

Answer (score 3):

Your Python files are not specially managed by Python itself. If you uninstall Python, source code files (files with the `.py` extension) won't be affected.

Comment: @fork this is true on any operating system, including Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There's no harm I can see in overwriting a pip installation. So, just follow the [instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and let us know if you have further problems:

1. Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).
2. Run python get-pip.py and get on with the rest of your stuff.

Comment: I think this is slightly dangerous advice without knowing what operating system the user is using, or what exactly their problem is.

Comment: Reinstalling pip will not pose any problem whatsoever on any platform I'm aware of -- windows, Linux, OpenBSD, Solaris, FreeBSD, NetBSD, Symbian. Have you experienced any "danger" from upgrading pip on a python installation?

Comment: I'd be skeptical of manually reinstalling Pip on Debian where Pip is usually provided as a separate package by APT. Maybe you've done it successfully and I'm wrong. But I wouldn't want to try it on my own system.

Comment: I agree there's perhaps no harm in a Pip upgrade, but the user also specifically mentions "uninstalling and reinstalling Python to fix pip", so it is perhaps worth calling out.

Answer (score 0):

Before uninstalling python, make sure all your python applications support the new python version.

My suggestion is to create virtual environments in your system to use multiple python versions

Try Anaconda - https://www.anaconda.com/ to create multiple virtual environments, where you can run a python version on each environment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you installed the Python or it came with the OS.

If you installed Python, it’s no problem at all — your files are safe and uninstalling Python won’t touch them.

If you’re planning on uninstalling the Python that came with your OS, I’d advise not do do that — it could cause a whole lot of trouble. Instead, you could install a new version of Python into your user directory and link to it by adding its location to the `PATH` variable used by your shell.